# Is there an easy way to convert all my Strings to references to strings.xml

Tags: java, android

While developing I always hard coded strings inside the Java classes. Now I need to translate my app, I am finding it difficult and tedious to move all the text to res/string.xml

Is there an easy/quick way to do this?

How difficult would it be possible to write a script to do this if there isn't one already?

Comment: you mean besides doing it right in the first place?

Comment: @MarcoForberg Besides going back in time yes

Comment: Netbeans had an internationalization option that will find all the hard-coded strings... If you can explore it a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you application whenever and in whichever activity you have defined a string hardcoded go into that activity and right **click>select Source>Click option Externalize  Strings...**

It will show you all the strings hardcoded in a dialog as below:

[image]

Check all the strings whichever you want to externalize and select next and it will directly give reference into separate files.

**OR**

Another way is select string which is hardcoded and right click and **Quick Fix>Extract String**

Which will open dialog as below and in it give the name of the string and it will directly enter the string into **strings.xml** file.

[image]